# Why screen navigation is not working in flutter local notifications?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigation

I am using `flutter_local_notifications` in my flutter app and onTaping the notification,I want to navigate to other screen.The notification is working but on taping it,It doesnt navigate to that particular screen.

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
    GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");

void initialize(BuildContext context) async {
  var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int? id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      var params = payload.split("_");
      print(params);

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewsPage(
                category: params[3],
                link: params[2],
                photo: params[4],
                summary: params[1],
                title: params[0])),
      );
    }
  });
}

void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    initialize(this.context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.light(), // Provide light theme.
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what I am using for setting up the notification and navigation,I think its a context error but need some help figuring it out.Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution using `get` package in flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/get

Instead of this:

```
MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewsPage(
                category: params[3],
                link: params[2],
                photo: params[4],
                summary: params[1],
                title: params[0])),
      );
```

Use this:

```
Get.to(NewsPage(
      category: params[3],
      link: params[2],
      photo: params[4],
      summary: params[1],
      title: params[0]));
```